# Get all week start dates in a month where week starts on specific day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to create a list of all week start dates, as strings from a given month start date, where the week runs Thursday to Friday.

For example, if the current date was Monday 1st January, I would begin collecting the week start dates in the month of January from December 28th.

My approach so far successfully gets each week start date in a given month, however, the results are based on the start of a week as a Monday, whereas I need it to start from the previous Thursday:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

month_start = '2021-02-01'
month_end = '2021-02-28'

dates = [
    d.strftime('%F') 
    for d in pd.date_range(month_start, month_end)
]

weeks = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(dates)).apply(
    lambda x: (x - timedelta(days=x.dayofweek))).unique()

weeks = [
    w.strftime('%F') 
    for w in pd.to_datetime(weeks)
]
```

Yields

> > > ['2021-02-01', '2021-02-08', '2021-02-15', '2021-02-22']

Desired outcome:

> > > ['2021-01-28', '2021-02-05', '2021-02-11', '2021-02-18', '2021-02-25']

Many thanks

Comment: your expected output looks wrong... not all dates are Thursday. `[d.strftime("%F") for d in pd.date_range(dt.date(2021,2,1), dt.date(2021,2,28), freq="W-THU")]`

Comment: It was just a contrived example for purposes of demonstration.

Comment: ok so above will work then - weekly Thursday freq.  no need to code yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta 
def find_last_thursday(month_start: str):
    d = pd.to_datetime(month_start)
    return d - timedelta((d.dayofweek + 4)%7)
list(pd.date_range(start = find_last_thursday(month_start), end = month_end, freq='7D')\
.to_series().apply(datetime.strftime, format= "%F"))
```

Comment: Thanks, although it is possible that the 1st week in a given month starts on a Thursday, and therefore this would add an additional time stamp?

Comment: That's right, assuming you don't want that, i.e., if Jan 1st is a Thursday and you'd like your list to start from Jan 1st. Modified my answer. A lot more intuitive now..

Comment: Many thanks, this satisfies the problem therefore!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the calendar module.

You can use the output into pandas if required.

The code is here:

```
import calendar

a=calendar.Calendar()
month=2
year=2021

#last thursday last month
c=a.monthdatescalendar(year,month-1)
last_thursday_last_month=c[-1][3]

#all thursday this month
d=a.monthdatescalendar(year,month)
thursdays_this_month=[]
for x in d:
    thursdays_this_month.append(x[3])

all_thursdays = [last_thursday_last_month] + thursdays_this_month

b=[]
for item in all_thursdays:
    b.append(item.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

print(b)
```

when executed:

```
$ python3 getthursdays.py
['2021-01-28', '2021-02-04', '2021-02-11', '2021-02-18', '2021-02-25']
```